# Correct way to GZip compress PUT content from .NET HttpClient?

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

I haven't been able to find any detailed information on using .NET HttpClient for sending compressed PUTs.   I have a Gzip compression class that can compress byte arrays, but I'm unsure if something like the below is the correct way to do things:

```
    public HttpRequestMessage GetHttpPutRequestMessage(string uri, string dataToPut, string username, string password)
    {
        var request = SetupHttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, uri, username, password);

        byte[] bytesToSend = _useCompression ? 
            _compressionService.Compress(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataToPut)) : Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataToPut);

        request.Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);

        return request;
    }

    private HttpRequestMessage SetupHttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod method, string uri, string username, string password)
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, uri);
        var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username + ":" + password);
        request.Headers.Authorization =
            new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
                "Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

        request.Headers.ExpectContinue = false;

        if (_usingEmulator)
            request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(_contentType));

        if (_useCompression)
        {
            request.Headers.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));
            request.Headers.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("deflate"));
        }

        return request;
    }
```

The compression class is very simple.  Compress method is below:

```
    public byte[] Compress(byte[] data)
    {
        using (var compressedStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var zipStream = new GZipStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
            {
                zipStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                zipStream.Close();
                return compressedStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seems ok at firght glance. Have you tried sending it to a server which accepts gzip?

Comment: I'd use streamcontent, much more efficient than holding the byte array.

Comment: @TimothyStepanski Thanks for the tip!  Do you have a link to show how to use streamcontent with httpclient?
Thanks!

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking here. Did you try this and it didn't work? Or are you looking for more of a general code review? If it's the latter it might be a better fit for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @ToddMenier couldn't try it against the client at the time, so was asking for advice.  As it turns out, it's fine and works fine.  Thanks, though, I didn't know about codereview.stasckexchange.com!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the way following on .net core.

```
'services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
            {
                options.Providers.Add<BrotliCompressionProvider>();
                options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
                options.EnableForHttps = true;
            });'

            'services.Configure<BrotliCompressionProviderOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Level = CompressionLevel.Fastest;
            });'

            'services.Configure<GzipCompressionProviderOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Level = CompressionLevel.Fastest;
            });'
```